# CSV Load - changing string to timestamp

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I need to load on a regular base big csv files into the neo4j (2.6 mio records per file). I could do this by opening the file and parsing line for line which allows to manipulate the records but is rather inperformant- so I would prefer to use the csv loader which is provided by neo4j.

Within a datarecord there are time values in a format like "2016-12-13T08:07:03+01". In order to work with them I would like to change them into unix-timestamps.

I have not found yet a cypher command / function which would turn a string into a timestamp, but maybe someone has an idea?

I came also upon APOC procedures but for whatever reason I could not getting them to work. I use a Win 7 Enterprise OS and have a Neo4J 3.1.0 community edition 64Bit running. I copied apoc-3.0.8.4-all.jar into the plugin folder of the current neo4j installation (Neo4j CE 3.1.0\plugins) and tried a CALL dbms.procedures() which seems only to show the current implemented procdures starting with db.xxx, and a CALL apoc.help("apoc") failed with "There is no procedure with the name `apoc.help` registered for this database instance.". So I assumed I need to copy this into the current neo4j instance I am using. So I created there a plugin folder and restarted the engine. This failed with "Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@803551' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.". Checking the debug.log I see warnings like

```
2017-01-10 06:42:02.382+0000 WARN  [o.n.k.i.p.Procedures] Failed to load `apoc.couchbase.CouchbaseConnection` from plugin jar `/D:/xxx/Neo4j/default.graphdb/plugins/apoc-3.0.8.4-all.jar`: com/couchbase/client/java/document/Document
2017-01-10 06:42:02.382+0000 WARN  [o.n.k.i.p.Procedures] Failed to load `apoc.couchbase.CouchbaseManager` from plugin jar `/D:/xxx/Neo4j/default.graphdb/plugins/apoc-3.0.8.4-all.jar`: com/couchbase/client/java/env/CouchbaseEnvironment
2017-01-10 06:42:02.382+0000 WARN  [o.n.k.i.p.Procedures] Failed to load `apoc.couchbase.document.CouchbaseUtils` from plugin jar `/D:/xxx/Neo4j/default.graphdb/plugins/apoc-3.0.8.4-all.jar`: com/couchbase/client/core/message/kv/MutationToken
2017-01-10 06:42:02.523+0000 WARN  [o.n.k.i.p.Procedures] Failed to load `apoc.mongodb.MongoDBColl` from plugin jar `/D:/xxx/Neo4j/default.graphdb/plugins/apoc-3.0.8.4-all.jar`: org/bson/conversions/Bson
2017-01-10 06:42:02.554+0000 WARN  [o.n.k.i.p.Procedures] Failed to load `apoc.schema.AssertSchemaProcedure` from plugin jar `/D:/xxx/Neo4j/default.graphdb/plugins/apoc-3.0.8.4-all.jar`: org/neo4j/kernel/api/proc/CallableProcedure$Context
```

There is no way to fix this w/o reinstalling Neo4J as even after deleting the plugin the instance doesnt start anymore.

Google doesnt help here really so I was hoping maybe someone has an idea how to either have a cypher function to convert those strings into a timestamp or knows how to resolve the apoc problem an dmaybe has even an example code for a timestamp change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a version targeting an older release (Neo4j 3.0.x).

From the looks of things, APOC is maintaining releases for 3.0.x installations while continuing development on the 3.1.x line.

Here is the [releases page](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/releases). If you scroll down you'll see there are 3.1.x releases too (latest as of 1/10/17 is 3.1.0.3), and these correspond with the version of Neo4j you're using. Use the latest of these releases instead.

As for this older install requiring a reinstall to fix, if that's accurate, it requires some attention from the maintainers of APOC (I've created an issue for this).

EDIT

Using the MacOS install, community version 3.1.0, while attempting to start with the older APOC jar causes an error and prevents startup, removing the jar allows it start up just fine. Maybe the corruption issue is specific to either the Windows or 64-bit Windows edition.

Comment: Awesome, I was mislead by "This release targets Neo4j 3.0.8 and later" assuming also Neo4J 3.1 was addressed. Using apoc-3.1.0.3-all.jar instead fixed the problem, thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem, it is confusing and something APOC maintainers should fix. I think this is the first time APOC has had separate branches being maintained in parallel with the recent Neo4j 3.1 release, so they've got a few fixes to make as far as their release process and notes.